# FindByIdAndUpdate creates an _id inside a nested object

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing an endpoint that accepts a basic invitation, I need to get a notification by an id provided in the parameters (suing express), and then update his `result` field. The interface/schema is like this:

```js
const NotiticationSchema = new Schema<Notitication>({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, default: null },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    navigation: {
        type: String,
        enum: NotificationNav,
        required: true
    },
    navigationId: {
        type: String,
        enum: NotificationIds,
        required: true
    },
    teamId: { type: String, required: true },
    result: {
        type: {
            accepted: { type: Boolean, required: true },
            motivation: { type: String, required: true }
        },
        default: null
    }
});
```

This is the code that I'm currently using:

```js
const notification = await NotiticationModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params["id"]!, { $set: { result: { accepted: true, motivation: null } } });
```

The expected output should be:

```json
{
  ...
  "result": {
    "accepted": true,
    "motivation": null
  }
}
```

What `NotiticationModel.findByIdAndUpdate()` does:

```json
{
  ...
  "result": {
    "accepted": true,
    "motivation": null,
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "65b23b495a60bda2c6e67996"
    }
  }
}
```

I've never encountered this behaviour, anyone can help?

P.S. I've already asked AI, it didn't give any useful advice.

Comment: From [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndUpdate()), *Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg, passing any options, and returns the found document (if any).* It should be returning the `_id` of your root document; not an _id of your subdocument. Can you confirm the final result of update by querying the database after update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. When you add an object to MongoDB then mongoose will automatically assign an `_id` property of type `ObjectId` to it.

To remove this feature pass the `_id: false` property into your schema for the relevant object like so:

```js
const NotiticationSchema = new Schema<Notitication>({
    //...
    teamId: { type: String, required: true },
    result: {
        type: {
            accepted: { type: Boolean, required: true },
            motivation: { type: String, required: true }
        },
        default: null,
        _id: false //< here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you should use the updateOne in stead of the findByIdAndUpdate

The findById I think replaces the entire document with new one.

Example

```
this.modal.updateOne({
  _id: params.id
}, {
    $set: {
       "result": {
          "accepted": true,
          "motivation": null
        }
    }
})
```